# How to select all the records that have different values only on particular columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to think of the query that will do the job, but I decided to ask you for help.

I have an Answer table, and an AnswerHistory table. In my BLL I have two separate methods that make updates to the Answer table. The first one is used when a user changes the Title or the Body columns of the Answer table. No matter, which of the two are updated, a new AnswerHistory is created, containing all the fields of the Answer entity, before the change took place. Meaning, if I change the title of an Answer entity from 'Title 1' to 'Title 2', I'll have a new AnswerHistory entity, having 'Title 1' in the Title column, as well as the date on which this change took place. Furthermore, the other function changes the IsAccepted column from 0 to 1 and vice versa. Of course, it also creates an AnswerHistory entity.

To sum up:
- Function 1 changes the title and the body, creates a new AnswerHistory entity (copy of the Answer entity, before the change took place);
- Function 2 changes the IsAccepted column only. Also creates a new Answer entity (copy of the Answer entity, before the change took place).

I want to execute such a query that will retrieve all AnswerHistory entities that were created as a result of running Function 1. Meaning, I want to select all AnswerHistories which came about after some user changed either the Title, or the Body of the original Answer entity. I don't want to retrieve the ones, that are created when a user changed the IsAccepted property of the Answer.

If I have the following data in the Answer table,

```
Id  QeustionId  Title     Body     IsAccepted   CreationUserId  CreationDate        
1   1           Title1_3  Body1_3  1            2               2014-07-22
2   2           Title2_1  Body2_1  1            2               2014-07-22
3   3           Title3_2  Body3_2  0            2               2014-07-22
```

And these entities in the AnswerHistory table

```
Id  AnswerId    Title     Body      IsAccepted  ModificationDate    
13  1           Title1_1  Body1_1   0           2014-08-06          
14  1           Title1_1  Body1_1   1           2014-09-06          
15  1           Title1_2  Body1_2   1           2014-10-06          
16  2           Title2_1  Body2_1   0           2014-08-06          
17  3           Title3_1  Body3_1   0           2014-08-06
```

My query should return:

```
Id  AnswerId    Title     Body      IsAccepted  ModificationDate            
14  1           Title1_1  Body1_1   1           2014-09-06          
15  1           Title1_2  Body1_2   1           2014-10-06              
17  3           Title3_1  Body3_1   0           2014-08-06
```

Is this possible, and if yes - then how?

By the way, **I do NOT want to change my schema** and create different history tables to handle the different scenarios - the one when the user changes the Title or the Body of the question, and another for the IsAccepted changes.

**Edit:**
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @paqogomez I'm assuming he means Microsoft's SQL Server, which would mean mssql

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: How come 16  2           Title2_1  Body2_1   0           2014-08-06 is not in the results.

Comment: History should really be handled by using Point in Time columns.

Comment: 16-2 is not in the results, because it came about as a result of changing the IsAccepted column's value (look at the Answer table).

I decided to take this approach, and not the Point in Time one, because I didn't (and still don't) want to have data repeatability (not sure if this is the correct term). Using this design, I have everything I need to know, without repetition and using less space :)

Comment: Why is 14 in your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put things directly in the answer history table when they are created?  Having the data split between two tables makes the query much harder to write.

Let's start with a CTE to get the real history (including current values).  Then add a method to do the comparison.   I will assume SQL Server 2012+, because the `lead()` function will be most useful.

```
with changes as (
      select Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate
      from AnswerHistory
      union all
      select NULL as Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate
      from Answer
     ),
     changeslead as (
      select c.*,
             lead(title) over (partition by AnswerId order by ModificationDate) as next_title,
             lead(body) over (partition by AnswerId order by ModificationDate) as next_body
      from changes c
     )
select id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate
from changeslead
where title <> next_title or body <> next_body;
```

This assumes that `title` and `body` are not `NULL`, which is consistent with how the question is phrased.

Answer (score 0):

First I create some test tables

use tempdb
--Create Test Tables
CREATE TABLE Answer
(ID int PRIMARY KEY, QuestionId int not null, Title  varchar(25) not null, Body  varchar(25) not null, IsAccepted bit not null, CreationUserId int not null, CreationDate date not null)

```
CREATE TABLE AnswerHistory 
(Id int not null PRIMARY KEY, AnswerId int not null, Title varchar(25) not null, Body varchar(25) not null, IsAccepted bit not null, ModificationDate date not null)
CREATE INDEX IX_AnswerHistory_AnswerID ON AnswerHistory(AnswerID)
go

--Populate Test Tables
INSERT Answer(Id, QuestionId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, CreationUserId, CreationDate) VALUES (1, 1, 'Title1_3', 'Body1_3', 1, 2, '2014-07-22')
INSERT Answer(Id, QuestionId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, CreationUserId, CreationDate) VALUES (2, 2, 'Title2_1', 'Body2_1', 1, 2, '2014-07-22')
INSERT Answer(Id, QuestionId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, CreationUserId, CreationDate) VALUES (3, 3, 'Title3_2', 'Body3_2', 0, 2, '2014-07-22')
INSERT INTO AnswerHistory(Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate) VALUES(13, 1, 'Title1_1', 'Body1_1', 0, '2014-08-06')
INSERT INTO AnswerHistory(Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate) VALUES(14, 1, 'Title1_1', 'Body1_1', 1, '2014-09-06')
INSERT INTO AnswerHistory(Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate) VALUES(15, 1, 'Title1_2', 'Body1_2', 1, '2014-10-06')
INSERT INTO AnswerHistory(Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate) VALUES(16, 2, 'Title2_1', 'Body2_1', 0, '2014-08-06')
INSERT INTO AnswerHistory(Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate) VALUES(17, 3, 'Title3_1', 'Body3_1', 0, '2014-08-06')
```

Once I'd created the test tables I did used a subquery to combine the current Answers and Answer History table into a single set of records using the UNION ALL clause. The Modification date is set to 31 Dec 9999 so that it will always be after the last History item.

```
SELECT Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate FROM AnswerHistory
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL as Id, ID AS AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, CONVERT(date,'9999-12-31')as ModificationDate FROM Answer
```

Then we use the LEAD Function in SQL server to get the next Title and Body for each row.

```
SELECT 
    u.Id, 
    u.AnswerId, 
    u.Title, 
    u.Body, 
    u.IsAccepted, 
    u.ModificationDate,
    Lead(Title) OVER (PARTITION BY u.AnswerId ORDER BY u.ModificationDate) as nextTitle,
    Lead(Body) OVER (PARTITION BY u.AnswerId ORDER BY  u.ModificationDate) as nextBody
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate FROM AnswerHistory

        UNION ALL 
        SELECT NULL as Id, ID AS AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, CONVERT(date,'9999-12-31')as ModificationDate FROM Answer
        )u --Union of historic and current queries
```

Which gives us

```
Id          AnswerId    Title           Body            IsAccepted ModificationDate nextTitle       nextBody
----------- ----------- --------------- --------------- ---------- ---------------- --------------- ---------------
13          1           Title1_1        Body1_1         0          2014-08-06       Title1_1        Body1_1
14          1           Title1_1        Body1_1         1          2014-09-06       Title1_2        Body1_2
15          1           Title1_2        Body1_2         1          2014-10-06       Title1_3        Body1_3
NULL        1           Title1_3        Body1_3         1          9999-12-31       NULL            NULL
16          2           Title2_1        Body2_1         0          2014-08-06       Title2_1        Body2_1
NULL        2           Title2_1        Body2_1         1          9999-12-31       NULL            NULL
17          3           Title3_1        Body3_1         0          2014-08-06       Title3_2        Body3_2
NULL        3           Title3_2        Body3_2         0          9999-12-31       NULL            NULL

(8 row(s) affected)
```

LEAD() Can't be used in a WHERE clause so this has to be wrapped in another sub query to wrap up the results allowing us to apply the filter.

```
SELECT 
w.Id ,w.AnswerId ,w.Title,w.Body ,w.IsAccepted ,w.ModificationDate 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    u.Id, 
    u.AnswerId, 
    u.Title, 
    u.Body, 
    u.IsAccepted, 
    u.ModificationDate,
    Lead(Title) OVER (PARTITION BY u.AnswerId ORDER BY  u.AnswerId,u.ModificationDate) as nextTitle,
    Lead(Body) OVER (PARTITION BY u.AnswerId ORDER BY  u.ModificationDate) as nextBody
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT Id, AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, ModificationDate FROM AnswerHistory
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT NULL as Id, ID AS AnswerId, Title, Body, IsAccepted, CONVERT(date,'9999-12-31')as ModificationDate FROM Answer
        )u --Union of historic and current queries
    )w --Subquery with windowed Functions
WHERE w.Body <> w.nextBody OR w.Title <> w.nextTitle
```

For more information on LEAD check Microsoft 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx

If you'd been using an earlier version of SQL Server you wouldn't have had this function available and it would be a lot more awkward to implement